# Steps involved in instantiation of Class?

Tags: java

When we write a statement like `Foo f = new Foo();` we know that JVM calls the Defaut `ClassLoader.loadClass()`, which return instance of `Class` , now how do we get our `Foo` instance from `Class` ?

Comment: R u trying to ask how to create instance using `Class` object ?

Comment: `Class.getConstructor().newInstance()` or `Class.newInstance()`

Comment: [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.kfupm.edu.sa%2Fics%2Flahouari%2FTeaching%2FJVM.ppt&ei=IkfNUbyNJ4jw0gXc4YD4Cg&usg=AFQjCNFG98UhbYSZhLtP1KfzhHzAZ0nTjA&sig2=-Tipu9-OI2LXQ37XXCuM6g) may be relevant?

Comment: basically i just wanted to have bit of idea on how ClassLoader,JVM work and use of Class class, and its role in instantiation process

Comment: The first is considered better... see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29

Comment: I think what you're searching in written [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html).

Comment: @LorenzoDematté      Google is an amazing thing, isn't it :p?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you're asking what code is executed when you create a new instance of a class, then the answer is that this is a primitive operation of the Java virtual machine, and there isn't any Java code involved.

The behaviour of instance creation is specified by the section [12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) of the Java Language Specification.

There is also a section on [4.10.2.4. Instance Initialization Methods and Newly Created Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.4) in the Java Virtual Machine Specification, but that's not all that interesting.

To find out what actually happens when you create an object, you would need to choose a JVM implementation and read its source code. Alternatively, you might do what most Java programmers do, and think of it as an essentially magical operation that just works!